# How can we encourage askers to accept answers?

Tags: discussion

There is a substantial amount of questions that are left open/hanging. Can we use the site layout or stickied topics or other means to encourage users to accept an answer?

Comment: related: [Let's stop displaying a user's accept rate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/136951/165773)

Comment: This is a problem on every site so would probably be best discussed on the global meta. I imagine that there are plenty of threads about it already though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's really no way.

I think Stack Exchange prompts you if you log in again, but if you forget you might never even notice you don't have an accepted answer. I know a few times this prompt has caused me to go through my older questions and accept answers. Every once in a while I get acceptances from answers I posted many months in the past too.

Sometimes (oftentimes?) people post a question and never return. Those people just will never accept answers since they never log in again.